# Draggable blocks glued with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Here is the [sample](http://codepen.io/gabyshev/pen/xGgOpy/) on codepen.

I use rails application and mongoDB at back end, jquery and **Draggabilly** library at front end.

Every time `dragEnd` or `focusout` events are triggered app tries to save card data to DB via ajax request. If there an error it return 422 code status with error message wich it displays in alert.

In that sample I emulate error message from app so that alert is always shown when `focusout` triggered from the input in the new card.

Problem:

1. Add a new card
2. Write some test name
3. And then click to other card to trigger `focusout`
4. Click 'OK' in alert
5. Click back to the previously added card

As you can see, two card are *glued* with each other.
Any suggestions how to avoid *glue* effect?

Comment: Which is the browser you are getting this problem in?

Comment: chrome latest version on both linux(ubuntu 14.04 x64) and windows (7 x64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is make all dragable elements disable for dragging when any input focused. And make them enabled back when ajax request is success.